# How can I tell Zuul CI to make a role available without running it on pre-run?

Tags: ansible, zuul-ci

I do have some roles that I want to run in `post` and currently if I add them to `roles`, they will be run automatically when the job is created, which is not really the desired behavior.

```yaml
job:
  name: myjob
  roles:
    - zuul: myorg/some-role
      name: some-role  # <-- zuul will auto-run this role before pre-run
      # how to add a role that can be consumed by post-run.yaml?
```

How to I convince Zuul CI to only install these roles in ansible path, so later we can import them from `pre-run.yaml` playbook?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In fact my assumption was incorrect, roles mentioned in job definition are not run by default, are only made available.